# Google OAuth2.0 NodeJS Authentication

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Could you help me figure out what's wrong with my code for google auth?
I'm developing a nodejs app that should connect to my Youtube account to start live-streaming my camera but i can't go past authentication phase.

I keep receiving the same error: "key must be a string, a buffer or an object" but i'm providing the credentials.json file as per downloaded from Google Console.. Thanks

index.js:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
 
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFilename: 'credentials.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
});

const youtube = google.youtube({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: auth
});
```

credentials.json:

```
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "myproj-xxxx",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```